# OBIEE: Procedure executed via Direct Query analysis is run twice. Why

Tags: obiee

In OBIEE I have created a direct query that runs stored procedure.

Procedure itself makes insert into a table and at the end another insert into log table.

As mentioned in the tile, from logs I can tell that procedure is executed twice. Is this a normal behavior for direct query in OBIEE?

Answer (score 0):

You have to trace what happens in the logs of both OBI and the database. It's definitely not "normal" as you put it, but as you don't specify which version you are using so it's impossible to say whether you're hitting a bug. By the way, an exact version is "12.2.1.4.200414" and not "12c".

In general, Direct Database Request are at best an exception case for OBIEE as it's an analytical platform and not a SQL interpreter.